# How can I hide my application?

Tags: facebook

I have created an application that should only be available as a tab on a page.
I don't want it to be findable over the search box from Facebook.
The same problem was already questioned here by another guy but without an answer: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108179
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry, I think I found the application in the search box only because I was still logged in as the developer of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Application to `Sandbox mode`, in the Settings->Advanced section.  This will only allow developers of the application to see it.

Comment: But it will still work in the tab of a page for non-developers?

Comment: It should be hidden from non-developers

Comment: Then it is useless for my case: I am looking for a solution to offer an app to everyone in a tab but at the same time it shouldn't turn up in the search entries because the application page looks kinda empty.

Comment: I believe that what you want is to *not* submit the application to the `Application Directory`.

Comment: I haven't even pressed on "Submit to Search"

Comment: Leave the application as it is.  It is an option in the Application settings, so if you don't want it to be searchable, don't submit it.

Comment: Okay, I think I have found it only because I was still logged in with the developer account.

Comment: need the same thing, i want to hide from search results to focus user to the page results, otherwise apps comes first and confuses user. (My app is tab application by the way, so no canvas usage needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want it to be found?

You don't want others to be able to add it as a tab to their pages too?
Or you do not have a canvas version so you don't want people to end up on a 404 page?

For the first case, there is a way to restrict your app to only a specific page or set of pages. I can give you more details if you want

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide it because it is in "development stage" so what you need to do is deactivate the "social discovery" under advanced configuration of your app, the sandbox mode will only allow usage from developers or people assigned to the roles tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In another Forum I've read, that FB plans to give the possibility for app to have no pages. Should wait for one of the next developer love